# PHP Limit number of results per page

Tags: php, pagination, filenames

I have a php search code that returns the results in the page. What I wanna do is limit the number of results per page to 10, and echo a link for more results.

My code is:

```
$dir = 'www/posts'; 
$exclude = array('.','..','.htaccess'); 
$q = (isset($_GET['q']))? strtolower($_GET['q']) : ''; 
if (!empty($q)) {
    $res = opendir($dir);
    while(false!== ($file = readdir($res))) { 
        if(strpos(strtolower($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) { 
            $last_dot_index = strrpos($file, ".");
            $withoutExt = substr($file, 0, $last_dot_index);
            $fpath = 'posts/'.$file;
            if (file_exists($fpath)) {
                echo "<a href='/search.php?post=$withoutExt'>$withoutExt</a>" . " on " . date ("d F Y ", filemtime($fpath)) ; 
                echo "<br>"; 
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($res); 
}
else {
    echo "";
}
```

I tried the $q->limit(10); but it doesnt work. Please help me write a working code.

Comment: Your search logic is in `search.php` file.

Comment: anyway, your code is so messy with spaces, comments and nice indentations we can't read it easily. `$q` being a GET parameter (string), what do you expect with `$q->limit(10)` ? Do you know what you are doing here ?

Comment: checking `isset()` then `empty()` is redundant.  Don't do this.

Comment: Do your target posts have an expected suffix?  Are they `.pdf`? `.txt`, `.html`?

Comment: Yes. the posts texts are retrieved from txt files

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dir = 'www/posts';
$exclude = array(
    '.',
    '..',
    '.htaccess'
);
$q = (isset($_GET['q'])) ? strtolower($_GET['q']) : '';
$results=[];
if (! empty($q)) {
    $res = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($res))) {
        if (strpos(strtolower($file), $q) !== false && ! in_array($file, $exclude)) {
            $last_dot_index = strrpos($file, ".");
            $withoutExt = substr($file, 0, $last_dot_index);
            $fpath = 'posts/' . $file;
            if (file_exists($fpath)) {
                $results[]="<a href='/search.php?post=$withoutExt'>$withoutExt</a>" . " on " . date("d F Y ", filemtime($fpath));
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($res);
}

foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result;
    echo "<br>";
}
if (count($results) > 10 ) {
    echo 'results is more than 10, but only 10 results is shown';
}
```

Comment: With your code it shows that the result has more than 10, but it doesnt restrict only 10 results... All results are still shown

Comment: Ya now it works. Now if I want to echo a "Show More" link to shown the rest of the hidden results, how can I achieve that? For example right now if there are total 15 results, it will show only 10, but if I want a show more link for rest of the 5 results, what I would have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely untested suggestion... I am happy to have a bit of back and forth to iron it out.

```
if(!empty($_GET['q'])){
    // perform some logical validation/sanitization on `$_GET['q']` for stability/security
    $path = '../posts'; // this relative path may need some adjusting
    $files=glob("$path/*.txt");  // collect all .txt files from the directory
    var_export($files);
    $filtered=preg_grep('~.*'.preg_quote($q,'/').'.*\.txt$~i',$files);  // case-insensitive filename search
    var_export($filtered);
    if(!empty($filtered)){
        $batches=array_chunk($filtered,10);  // store in groups of 10
        var_export($batches); // check the data
        if(!isset($_GET['page'],$batches[--$page])){  // a page has been submitted and that page exists in the batches array (subtract one to sync the page with the index)
            $page=0;
        }
        $leftovers=array_keys(array_diff_key($batches,[$page=>'']));
        foreach($batches[$page] as $filename){
            $withoutExt=substr($filename,0,strrpos($filename,"."));
            $fpath="posts/$filename";
            echo "<div><a href='/search.php?post=$withoutExt'>$withoutExt</a> on ",date("d F Y",filemtime($fpath)),"</div>";
        }
        // here you can list the other pages available from this search
        if($leftovers){
            echo "Additional pages:";
            foreach($leftovers as $offset){
                echo " <a href='/search.php?q={$_GET['q']}&page=",++$offset,"'>$offset</a>";
            }
        }
    }
}else {
    echo "No Search Terms found";
}
```

Comment: Can you show me in the code here: https://pastebin.com/PtCpT9Es . The only thing this lacks is the "Show more" feature or the $leftovers function of your code.

Comment: Nah.  I don't want to do it like that.  I am deliberately using `glob()` and array functions to do the work.  This all sets up the "Show more" component.  I am happy to support you in regard to my snippet (I'm sure it won't run as it is)  but if you are willing to set up some checkpoints, I can assist in getting it working.